# Parametro "undefined" al querer usar un string en Angular2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular2-template

estoy intentado pasar un id por de un div a un componente hijo, este me funciona si es que lo uso en el template del componente hijo, pero al querer usarlo en el código este me aparece como undefined

componente padre con su respectivo template

```js
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Tables} from '../single-table-component/single.table.component';
 
@Component({
 selector:'table-component',
 templateUrl: 'table.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent{

 constructor(
    ){
  
 }

}
```

```html
  <ngb-panel id="static-1" title="GASTOS REMUNERACIONALES" id="gastoRemuneracionales" #parentInput (click)='0'  class="cd col-md-12">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
         <tables [parentValue]="parentInput.id"></tables>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
```

el id `id="gastoRemuneracionales"` es el que quiero pasarle al hijo mediante 

`<tables [parentValue]="parentInput.id"></tables>`

código del componente hijo

```js
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {TableComponent} from '../table-component/table.component';

 @Component({
 selector: 'tables',
 templateUrl: './single.table.component.html',
 inputs: ['parentValue']
})
export class Tables{
 closeResult: string;
 title:string = 'hola mundo';
 datos: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
 public parentValue:string;

 constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private af : AngularFireDatabase) {
   console.log(this.parentValue+  this.title)
   this.af.list('/subvencionEscolar/'+ this.parentValue); 
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped tb col-md-12">
   <thead>
    <th>N°</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Detalles</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>{{parentValue}}</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let mocks of datos | async">
       <th>{{mocks.id}}</th>
          <th> {{mocks.name}} </th>
          <td> <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary">Launch demo modal</button>
</td>
          <td>{{mocks.detail.montodoc}}</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

en el template del hijo se recibe sin ningún problema 

`<th>{{parentValue}}</th>`

pero en el código me muestra undefined 

`constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private af : AngularFireDatabase) {
    console.log(this.parentValue+  this.title)
    this.af.list('/subvencionEscolar/'+ this.parentValue);

}`

el console log me muestra "undefinedhola mundo" donde el hola mundo es el this.title
:c
Soy nuevo en angular, y he buscado por todos lados, siempre llegando al mismo resultado, de antemano gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Buenas. Entiendo que el problema que tienes es que no puedes usar el valor "id" ¿en el componente padre?. ¿O en el componente hijo?. Aún así la forma en la que pasas el dato entre los componentes no es correcta.

Comment: no me funciona en el componente hijo, solo en su template, pero al querer trabajarlo en el archivo .ts me dice que es undefined

Comment: Ahora te contesto, porque la forma en la que lo estás pasando no es correcta. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas, como te ponía en el comentario no me queda muy claro donde estás teniendo el problema de undefined si en el padre o en el hijo. De todos modos te dejo un enlace con como se pasan en Angular datos desde un componente padre a su hijo y viceversa. [Uso de Input y Output](http://www.codingmemoirs.com/2017/02/10/enviando-datos-entre-componentes-en-angular-2/)

Ahora en tu caso concreto para pasar el id sería algo así:

Componente padre:

```js
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Tables} from '../single-table-component/single.table.component';
 
@Component({
 selector:'table-component',
 templateUrl: 'table.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent{
 id: any;
 name: any;
 detail:any;

 constructor(
    ){
    // Tienes que dar valor a tu variable aun que entiendo que ya lo haces en alguna parte del código    pero que no lo has puesto aquí.
    this.id = 'Hola Mundo';
    }

}
```

```html
  <ngb-panel id="static-1" title="GASTOS REMUNERACIONALES" id="gastoRemuneracionales" #parentInput (click)='0'  class="cd col-md-12">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
         <tables [parentValue]="id"></tables>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
```

Componente hijo:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {TableComponent} from '../table-component/table.component';

 @Component({
    selector: 'tables',
    templateUrl: './single.table.component.html'
})
export class Tables{
    closeResult: string;
    title:string = 'hola mundo';
    datos: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
    //public parentValue:string;
    @Input() parentValue: string;

    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private af : AngularFireDatabase) {
            console.log(this.parentValue+  this.title)
            this.af.list('/subvencionEscolar/'+ this.parentValue);  
        }
}
```

Debes de recoger el valor en el hijo utilizando @Input() nombreDeLaVariableQueRecibe: tipoDeVariable

Comment: lo que pasa, es que el id que necesito enviar es el id de un div que se encuentra en el template, editare el post para dejarlo mas claro, me sigue mostrando undefined

Comment: Bueno pero el id de ese div no lo conoces? Quiero decir ese valor en inmutable no?. Puedes pasarlo igualmente.

Comment: si conozco el id del div, pero varios div ejecutan el evento con
<tables [parentValue]="parentInput.id"></tables> donde cada div tiene un #parentInput y un (click)='0'

por lo tanto cada vez que hago click en un div se le pasa la id que contenga ese div

Comment: Solucionadoooo, estaba todo bien, lo que me ayudaste también, el  problema estaba en que quería usar la variable en el constructor, y por ahí lei que este se inicia primero que todo en el componente, ngOnInit se inicia cuando el componente ya cargo, use la variable ahí dentro y listo funciono enseguida

Comment: Me alegro que hayas dado con la solución.